# I2cReadByte, bad handle, Pigpio c++ Library

Tags: pi-3, c++, pigpio

I recently bought on ebay a sensor for a drone project im working on [MPU9250 BMP280 10DOF](https://www.ebay.com/itm/MPU9250-BMP280-10DOF-Acceleration-Gyroscope-Compass-Nine-Shaft-Sensor-GY-91-/322878981797?hash=item4b2d1646a5) the thing is i always get a "bad handle" error, and honestly i cant figure it out.

> 2017-11-18 22:10:03 i2cReadByte: bad handle (-74)
>   Valor de 0x3B: -25

note:  the "Valor de 0x3B" its just for info purpose

in this example im trying to retrieve the X axis of the accelerometer

i dont know if its a bad conecction or an error on the code, but to be sure can anyone check it just in case, my code its as follows

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "../pigpio.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

/*   Leer datos del sensor usando I2C
 * 
*/
int main(void) {

typedef int *Acc;      // Defino un handle (Apuntador) // not sure about this one
gpioInitialise();      // inicializa la libreria
if (gpioInitialise() <=0)
   {  
      std::cout << "gpio not initialise";
      return 0;
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "gpio working fine" << std::endl;
   } 


  //i2cOpen(0,0x3B,0); habro el i2c y leeo la informacion en la direccion 0x3b
  //i2cOpen(Bus seleccionado, Direccion sensor, Flag debe ser 0)
 //Acc i2cOpen(0,0x3B,0);  

for (;;)
{
  std::cout << "Valor de 0x3B: "<< i2cReadByte (i2cOpen(0,0x3B,0)) << std::endl; // Leeo informacion del bus, menos codigo
}

gpioTerminate();
return 0;
}
```

I wired the follow pins on the sensor to the I2c conecctions on the pi

> Sensor --- RP3
>
> > 3,3v to pin 1
> >
> > Gnd to pin 9
> >
> > SCL to Pin 5
> >
> > SDA to pin 3

Answer (score 2):

On most Pis you need to use I2C bus 1.  I2C bus 0 is pretty much reserved for system use with HATs etc.

The first parameter to [i2cOpen](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#i2cOpen) is the bus.

```
int i2cOpen(unsigned i2cBus, unsigned i2cAddr, unsigned i2cFlags)
This returns a handle for the device at the address on the I2C bus.

  i2cBus: >=0
 i2cAddr: 0-0x7F
i2cFlags: 0
```

I suggest you change `i2cOpen(0,0x3B,0)` to `i2cOpen(1,0x3B,0)`.

Comment: you where right, i was using the wrong bus, now im using bus 1 and recieving data, also moved the `i2cOpen()` out of the Loop, that was the main problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ok for some odd reason you cant use i2cOpen INSIDE a loop, that was the main issue, also the bus was wrong (i was using bus 0) i switched to bus 1 just like joan sugested, also im using `i2cReadByteData` instead of `i2cReadByte` , the first one retrieves data from an especific address, and the second one its for one type of data only

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "../pigpio.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>


/*   Leer datos del sensor usando I2C
*  Addres of MPU-9250 :0x68
*/

int main(void) {

int sensor; //handler for the sensor

gpioInitialise();      // inicializa la libreria

if (gpioInitialise() <=0)  // check if library its working
   {  
      std::cout << "gpio not initialise";
      return 0;
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "gpio working fine" << std::endl;
   } 

//i2cOpen(1,0x68,0); enable i2c comms, bus is 1, the addres of the sensor is 0x68
//i2cOpen(Bus seleccionado, Direccion sensor, Flag debe ser 0) 

sensor = i2cOpen(1,0x68,0); // handler its a variable, in this case sensor, NEVER INSIDE A LOOP!!!!!
for (;;)
{
   // Reading Gyroscope data
   std::cout << "Gyro 'Y': " << i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x46) << "   ";
   std::cout << "Gyro 'X': " << i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x44) << "   ";
   std::cout << "Gyro 'Z': " << i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x48) << "   ";
   std::cout << "Temperatura: " << i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x42) << std::endl;
}

gpioTerminate();
return 0;
}
```

now im receiving data from the sensor, its a little odd because it spikes all over the place, probably its noise but i will try filter it.

heres what i get from the sensor

```
gpio working fine
Gyro 'Y': 217   Gyro 'X': 208   Gyro 'Z': 124   Temperatura: 16
Gyro 'Y': 239   Gyro 'X': 13   Gyro 'Z': 128   Temperatura: 144
Gyro 'Y': 247   Gyro 'X': 255   Gyro 'Z': 130   Temperatura: 176
Gyro 'Y': 4   Gyro 'X': 2   Gyro 'Z': 114   Temperatura: 160
Gyro 'Y': 229   Gyro 'X': 6   Gyro 'Z': 130   Temperatura: 112
Gyro 'Y': 11   Gyro 'X': 251   Gyro 'Z': 141   Temperatura: 16
Gyro 'Y': 13   Gyro 'X': 13   Gyro 'Z': 135   Temperatura: 144
Gyro 'Y': 250   Gyro 'X': 237   Gyro 'Z': 148   Temperatura: 144
Gyro 'Y': 249   Gyro 'X': 3   Gyro 'Z': 137   Temperatura: 160
Gyro 'Y': 11   Gyro 'X': 250   Gyro 'Z': 138   Temperatura: 160
Gyro 'Y': 18   Gyro 'X': 232   Gyro 'Z': 145   Temperatura: 176
Gyro 'Y': 245   Gyro 'X': 202   Gyro 'Z': 135   Temperatura: 176
Gyro 'Y': 15   Gyro 'X': 220   Gyro 'Z': 87   Temperatura: 144
Gyro 'Y': 8   Gyro 'X': 228   Gyro 'Z': 125   Temperatura: 224
Gyro 'Y': 250   Gyro 'X': 236   Gyro 'Z': 135   Temperatura: 176
Gyro 'Y': 3   Gyro 'X': 242   Gyro 'Z': 127   Temperatura: 144
Gyro 'Y': 237   Gyro 'X': 238   Gyro 'Z': 129   Temperatura: 176
Gyro 'Y': 17   Gyro 'X': 221   Gyro 'Z': 122   Temperatura: 176
Gyro 'Y': 15   Gyro 'X': 14   Gyro 'Z': 141   Temperatura: 224
Gyro 'Y': 22   Gyro 'X': 29   Gyro 'Z': 148   Temperatura: 176
Gyro 'Y': 13   Gyro 'X': 5   Gyro 'Z': 130   Temperatura: 160
Gyro 'Y': 228   Gyro 'X': 185   Gyro 'Z': 92   Temperatura: 176
Gyro 'Y': 0   Gyro 'X': 242   Gyro 'Z': 144   Temperatura: 144
Gyro 'Y': 12   Gyro 'X': 252   Gyro 'Z': 116   Temperatura: 176
Gyro 'Y': 7   Gyro 'X': 251   Gyro 'Z': 118   Temperatura: 144
Gyro 'Y': 27   Gyro 'X': 219   Gyro 'Z': 118   Temperatura: 176
Gyro 'Y': 17   Gyro 'X': 13   Gyro 'Z': 115   Temperatura: 144
Gyro 'Y': 11   Gyro 'X': 244   Gyro 'Z': 125   Temperatura: 208
Gyro 'Y': 52   Gyro 'X': 231   Gyro 'Z': 120   Temperatura: 160
Gyro 'Y': 38   Gyro 'X': 216   Gyro 'Z': 131   Temperatura: 64
Gyro 'Y': 50   Gyro 'X': 41   Gyro 'Z': 146   Temperatura: 160
Gyro 'Y': 17   Gyro 'X': 235   Gyro 'Z': 145   Temperatura: 144
Gyro 'Y': 25   Gyro 'X': 218   Gyro 'Z': 140   Temperatura: 144
Gyro 'Y': 28   Gyro 'X': 208   Gyro 'Z': 134   Temperatura: 176
Gyro 'Y': 16   Gyro 'X': 232   Gyro 'Z': 146   Temperatura: 176
Gyro 'Y': 22   Gyro 'X': 211   Gyro 'Z': 150   Temperatura: 176
Gyro 'Y': 249   Gyro 'X': 229   Gyro 'Z': 161   Temperatura: 176
Gyro 'Y': 27   Gyro 'X': 233   Gyro 'Z': 167   Temperatura: 144
Gyro 'Y': 36   Gyro 'X': 234   Gyro 'Z': 146   Temperatura: 160
Gyro 'Y': 4   Gyro 'X': 250   Gyro 'Z': 125   Temperatura: 112
Gyro 'Y': 14   Gyro 'X': 237   Gyro 'Z': 153   Temperatura: 160
Gyro 'Y': 59   Gyro 'X': 234   Gyro 'Z': 172   Temperatura: 160
Gyro 'Y': 21   Gyro 'X': 221   Gyro 'Z': 133   Temperatura: 240
```

Comment: You could use i2cOpen in the loop if you have a corresponding i2cClose in the loop.  However I believe it is more usual to open/close I2C just once in a program.